# Why I cannot assert that the job has been dispatched?

Tags: php, laravel, jobs, laravel-5.7

I have the following Laravel Controller:

```
namespace App\Controller;

use App\Jobs\MyJob;

class JobDispatchControler
{
   public function callJob(Request $request)
   {
     MyJob::dispatch();
   }
}
```

The controller above has the following route:

```
Route::get('/job',"\App\Controller\JobDispatchControler@callJob");
```

And I want to test whether I a call to the `/job` will dispatch the `MyJob` job:

```
namespace Test\App\MyJob;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Queue;
use App\Jobs\MyJob;

class TestDispatchJob extends TestCase
{
   public function testJobDispatch()
   {
     Queue::fake();
     self::get("/job");
     Queue::assertPushed(MyJob::class);
   }
}
```

But Once I run via phpunit the test I get the following error:

```
Time: 4.63 seconds, Memory: 34.00 MB

There was 1 failure:

1) Test\App\MyJob::testJobDispatch
The expected [App\Jobs\MyJob] job was not pushed.

/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Testing/Fakes/QueueFake.php:33
/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php:237
/var/www/html/tests/App/MyJob/TestDispatchJob.php:26

FAILURES!
Tests: 1, Assertions: 1, Failures: 1.
```

Do you know why I fail to assert that my job jas not been dispatched?

## Edit 1

According to this [article](https://medium.com/the-andela-way/mock-testing-in-laravel-4a2fe15885b8) I changed my test into:

```
namespace Test\App\MyJob;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Bus;
use App\Jobs\MyJob;

class TestDispatchJob extends TestCase
{
   public function testJobDispatch()
   {
     Bus::fake();
     self::get("/job");
     Bus::assertDispatched(MyJob::class);
   }
}
```

And still get the following error:

```
FAILURES!
Tests: 1, Assertions: 1, Failures: 1.

Time: 4.63 seconds, Memory: 34.00 MB

There was 1 failure:

1) Test\App\MyJob::testJobDispatch
The expected [App\Jobs\MyJob] job was not dispatched.

/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Testing/Fakes/BusFake.php:32
/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php:237
/var/www/html/tests/App/MyJob/TestDispatchJob.php:26

FAILURES!
Tests: 1, Assertions: 1, Failures: 1.
```

But once instead of triggering the `get` method arbitary dispach the job seems to work ok:

```
namespace Test\App\MyJob;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Bus;
use App\Jobs\MyJob;

class TestDispatchJob extends TestCase
{
   public function testJobDispatch()
   {
     Bus::fake();
     MyJob::dispatch();
     Bus::assertDispatched(MyJob::class);
   }
}
```

Comment: return a response from the controller method and assert that it is received in order to ensure your route is ok.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing it with `$this` instead of `self`? This way the job should be dispatched.c

```
public function testJobDispatch()
{
    Bus::fake();
    $response = $this->get('/job');

    Bus::assertDispatched(MyJob::class);
}
```